# MVC EF doesn't seem to be picking up row updates in a timely fashion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am tracking whether the user can access certain pages of the website using a custom AuthorizeAttribute and a table within the database that holds their username and role.  If I change a user's role, whether just through SQL or application page, the application doesn't seem to pick it up for some time, it varies.  It may pick it up right away or take 5-10 minutes or worse.  The problem with this is after their role has been changed they are still able to access pages they shouldn't be allowed.  The changes are taking affect on the database side, if you query the table the changes were made.  This doesn't seem to be happening anywhere else within my project.  Editing another table seems to reflect the changes just fine.

Custom Authorize Attribute:

```
private QIEducationEntities db = new QIEducationEntities();

public String Roles { get; set; }

protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    String userName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
    User user = db.Users.Include("UserRole").FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);

    if (user != null) {
        String[] rolesList = Roles.Split(',');
        foreach (String role in rolesList)
        {
            if (user.UserRole.UserRole1 == role)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    Uri requestUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer;
    if (requestUrl != null)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(requestUrl.ToString());
        filterContext.Controller.TempData["PopupMessage"] = "You are not currently authorized to view that page.";
    }
    else
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                                        { "action", "NotAuthorized" },
                                        { "controller", "Admin" }
                                    });
    }
}
```

Editing the user's role action (Also shows the attribute):

```
//
//GET: Admin/EditUser

[AuthorizeUser(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult EditUser(int id)
{
    User user = db.Users.Single(u => u.UserID == id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.UserRoles, "UserRoleID", "UserRole1", user.UserRole);
    return View(user);
}

//
//POST: Admin/EditUser

[AuthorizeUser(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUser(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Users.Attach(user);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("AllUsers");
    }
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.UserRoles, "UserRoleID", "UserRole1", user.UserRole);
    return View(user);
}
```

The view (if relevant):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                User Name:
            </th>
            <td class="table-row">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                Role:
            </th>
            <td class="table-row">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Role,
                    @ViewBag.Roles as SelectList, "",
                    new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = " -- Select Role -- " })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserRole)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="table-row-blank"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="table-row-button">
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="button" class="button" value="Cancel" 
                    onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AllUsers")'" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //DropDownList chosen plugin hook-up
            $('.chzn-select').prepend("<option></option>")
            $('.chzn-select').chosen({ width: "100%" });
        });
    </script>
}
```

So, is there something slightly off when editing that the database context in my project isn't picking up the changes?

Or is there some amount of time that elapses between "updating" values in the database context?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instantiating (and disposing) your `QIEducationEntities` class in the `AuthorizeCore` method. The framework is caching your AuthorizeUser action filter and the `db` instance variable along with it. Moving this into `AuthorizeCore` will ensure that it is created for each request.

Comment: Yep, that seems to have done it.  Almost always something small and simple.